# Express and React js: deal with api request, proxy?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

My situation:

I'm using Express and passport.js as my backend API server and React js as my front-end.

What I'm currently facing is that I keep getting index.html file when I request my passport auth by "/api/auth/*". However, it works as I expected when I'm making a request from my front-end via proxy.

So I tried using Regex to exclude "/api/*" route from using static build files.

```
app.use('/api', api)

app.use(/^\/(?!api).*/, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../build')))

app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../build/index.html'))
})
```

But not like my expectation, I just got Unexpected token < warning ...

How can I get my get "/api" route to work also while using React js build files?

Or should I just keep making a proxy request from React js dev server?

I want to understand how Express and React js app deployed in some server work together.